# Question about React Native Maps and Markers

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

So I have a school assignment soon, and I was wondering if someone could help me with something, and that is my class assignment is basically to map a route, so therefore every time a user clicks mark on a button it will create a marker for them. However, I have no idea how to create multiple markers...

Comment: I think it's easier if you share with me some progress. Why can't you create multiple markers? Is the map rendered?

Comment: I can help you. Do you have any starter code that you can share?